# React: React-Firebase-Hooks not getting value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, next.js

I am using this package [React-Firebase-Hooks](https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/aeadd15b3f8ca642f52776edf2e4dad62a00d449/firestore#usedocument) but I am not very sure how to properly use it.

In my code below, `user.data().username` is shown correctly but after putting it in `useState`, the username is not shown.  What was not done correctly here?

```
const [user, loading, error] = useDocument(
  firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid),
  {
    snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
  }
);

const [username, setUsername] = useState(user && user.data().username);

return (
  <div className="flex">
    <div className="w-1/2">
      {user && (
        <div className="p-8">
          <div>{user.data().username}</div>
          <div>{username}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
    <div className="w-1/2">Box 2</div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: why do a need a useState here?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I will be adding a input field allowing user to change username.

Comment: ok. btw if you put the value of username in state, just changing state won't change the value on firebase. You will need to update the firebase doc too.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal yes, that I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not getting the value on state because when the `useState` is initialized, `user` doesn't has a value, it's still loading. Since state is initialized only once, when the data from firebase loads, state doesn't changes.
You need to use a useEffect hook to watch for change in user, and `setUsername` then.

```
const [user, loading, error] = useDocument(
  firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid),
  {
    snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
  }
);

const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    setUsername(user.data().username);
  }
}, [user])

return (
  <div className="flex">
    <div className="w-1/2">
      {user && (
        <div className="p-8">
          <div>{user.data().username}</div>
          <div>{username}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
    <div className="w-1/2">Box 2</div>
  </div>
);
```

This should work, if you face any issues, leave a comment.